# Positioning things inside a DIV (css-related)

Tags: css, html

i'll try to make my question really simple 2 you

Basically, i have a DIV, in which i have a picture

**What CSS styles** should i apply to the picture to position it correctly inside the div
with the condition that everytime i resize the browser window it **stays there** (inside the div) at the same distance from the borders

Sorry for wasting your time but i'm still a newbie which needs help, thank you alot!

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22271794/model.PNG)

code

html

```
<div id="super_div">
<img id="eyes" src="images/eyes.png" />
</div>
```

css

```
that's the question :)
```

Comment: Where in the div? Maybe provide an example.

Comment: Always include your code in your questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look at absolute positioning. First, you set the containing div's position attribute to relative. For example:

```
#super_div
{
  position: relative;
}
```

Then, you set the image's position property to absolute and use the top and left or right properties to place it inside the parent div. So, for example:

```
#eyes
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

That's how you make the image keep its current position no matter what. [Here's a link to an  article explaining the basics.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This will get it horizontally centered:

```
margin:auto;
```

If you need it vertically centered as well then things get a bit more tricky. You can either resort to tables, use a background image (if this is appropriate to your situation) or fiddle with the css. I used the code on http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/ as a basis for solving a similar situation I had a while ago..